# Unable to download zip file on windows 8 using powershell script

Tags: powershell

I am trying to download a sigcheck zip file using a PowerShell script but it does not download. I see 1 zip file gets created in the C:\ drive which is invalid.

I am running the following:

```
$url = "https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/sigcheck"
$output = "C:\sigcheck.zip"
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $url -OutFile $output
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The URL you specified was not the actual file, but a page with the link to the file on it.

You need to use the following URL:

```
$url = 'https://download.sysinternals.com/files/Sigcheck.zip'
$output = "C:\sigcheck.zip"
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $url -OutFile $output
```

Comment: Thank you so much Mark, appreciate quick response. It work is working fine for me now. Once again thank you so much.